# How can i place a child div on a fixed position of a parent div that when i change place of parent then child should move automatically?

Tags: html, css

In my webpage, I have a div for my header.

```
 <div id="top-bar">
      <div id="headbar">
            <img src="images/headbar.jpg" border="0" alt="">
         <div id="loginbtn"><img src="images/loginbtn.png" border="0" alt=""></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

css for this is following:

```
 body 
 { 
margin:0; 
padding:0 
 }

  # headbar 
 { 
background:#A4DF00;
width: 1019px;
height: 185px;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
 }

 # top-bar
 {
background:#AFDF04;
height: 187px;
 }

 # loginbtn
{
width: 160px;
hight: 69px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 830px;
}
```

I wanted my header to be in the middle when user increases the explorer size. Thats working fine. Using this css login button's place is fixed. I want fixed place of login in button in header div. When user increase the explorer size and header keeps in center, then login button should also hold its right place in header div. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add:

```
#headbar {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: This is right! `position: absolute;` refers to the next parent-element with `position: relative;`.

Comment: Anyway, just to add on, you can use right: instead of left:, this is optional but I guess it'll be easier for you to specify the gap from the right edge.

Answer (score 1):

You have positioned the login button 'absolute', while you want it to be relative to the header bar (i.e. absolutely positioned *relative* to the header bar). Also, it seems your login button is on the right side of your header bar, judging the size and position. So you might just as well delete `position: absolute` and apply

```
float: right;
```

and some margin, say

```
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
```

to get it fixed on the spot you want.